# Bayesian network learning can be derived from learning each conditional distribution separately?

Tags: bayesian-network

Please helm 
I am wondering if we consider a learning the  parameter of a  bayesian network ,with  a training set ,where each training set is a vector of values containing all the random variable ,in the network .,Now can we show that the learning parameter of the network according to the MLE ,can be derived by seperately learning the parameters of each conditional distribution

Comment: I'm assuming the conditions are completely disjoint and the frequency of each condition is known in advance?

Comment: yes probability  of the marginal distributions are known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is explained in the paper [Decomposing Parameter Estimation Problems](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~krefaat/refaat14.pdf) by Refaat et al (2014).